# What is the best way to plot 30 dimensional SVM output in R?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, svm

I'm trying to apply a non-linear SVM, to separate my data (~30 features to predict disease (0 = no PH, 1= PH) in ~100 patients). I've been testing lots of different kernels, gamma values and cost values to try and get the best classification result.

Here's an example of my data:

| No | F2. | F3 | F4 | F5. | F6. | F7 | ... | F30 | BMI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63.97 | -1.39 | -12.35 | -1.50 | -10.42 | 8.06 | ... | -1.41 | 28.07 |
| 2 | 52.53 | -8.81 | 10.20 | 1.00 | -11.50 | 15.73 | ... | 0.742 | 20.30 |
| 3 | 46.93 | -0.82 | 6.31 | 13.20 | 8.31 | 1.58 | ... | -3.74 | 29.02 |
| 99 | -42.01 | -39.69 | 6.58 | 15.43 | 2.88. | 2.44 | ... | 0.10 | 38.44 |

I'd like to be able to visualise the hyperplane/decision boundary in some way, but I'm a bit stuck on how to do it. I gather that the best way to approach the problem is to either use some kind of dimension reduction method like PCA or to just pick 2 or 3 features to plot. My problem is that I don't know which variables would be the best to visualise out of my dataset (I'm trying to work out which of these features might be important), and I don't really know how to project the SVM output into a useful lower dimension.

This is the sort of thing I've tried so far:

```
library(e1071)

classifierS = svm(formula = PH ~ .,
data = training_set,
type = 'C-classification',
kernel = 'sigmoid', 
gamma = 0.5, 
cost = 0.5)

y_predS = predict(classifierS, newdata= test_set)

cmS = table(table(test_set$PH, y_predS)

plot(classifierS, test_set, formula=F15~BMI, fill=TRUE, grid=50)
```

[image: I'm not sure how to interpret the output I get from the attached plot, and other combinations are even more confusing!]

I also tried plotting a PCA of the support vectors, but I don't know how to relate these points to original data to e.g. colour by the success of the SVM separation.

```
pc <- prcomp(classifierS$SV)
plot(pc$x[,1:2])
```

I was hoping to generate something like the plots in this link:

https://vitalflux.com/svm-rbf-kernel-parameters-code-sample/

Comment: This does not seem like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. General data visualization questions might be a better fit for [stats.se] instead. It's not clear what exactly a "best" visualization would be -- that's very subjective and depends on what story you are trying to tell with your data.